# Threads hang after one iteration

Tags: c, pthreads, freeze

I've got a program which is supposed to simulate a Hotel.
This includes Guest threads which are supposed to interact with a Check-In thread and a Check-Out thread.

I compile using "gcc -pthread HotelProject_v4.c"
and execute with "./a.out"

My output looks great for "Guest 0", but once it reaches the end of it's Guest() thread, the last line "Recieve $x from Guest 0...", it hangs as if it's waiting for the next guests to talk.

I realize that the problem in my code is most likely within the `Main()` method, but for the sake of saving time if I'm wrong, I've attached the entire program.

The `Main()` method is at the bottom of the Code Block.

---

**Code:**

```
//Hotel Project 
//This project creates a system to simulate a hotel.

#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUM_GUESTS  10 //10 guests

/*GLOBAL VARIABLE*/ int globalVar0; // Check-in guestID
/*GLOBAL VARIABLE*/ int globalVar1; // Check-out guestID
/*GLOBAL VARIABLE*/ int globalVar2; // Check-out room

void *CheckIn(void *); // the two threads
void *CheckOut(void *);

pthread_t guests[NUM_GUESTS];
pthread_t desk[2];

sem_t roomSem;              //total number of rooms in the hotel
sem_t check_in, check_out;  //reception desks
sem_t s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;   //global semaphores

int rooms[5] = {1,1,1,1,1}; //keep track of availability of each room

int total_guests;       //incremented with each guest check-out
int pool;               //incremented with each guest use pool
int resturant;          //incremented with each guest use resturant
int fitness_center;     //incremented with each guest use fitness center
int business_center;    //incremented with each guest use business center

struct thread_data
{
    int guest_id;   // id number of guest
    int room;       // room guest utilizes
    int event;      // 0=swim, 1=resturaunt, 2=fitness, 3=business
    int cost;       // final cost of stay (random value)
};

struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS]; // array initialization

void *Guest(void *guestData)
{
int guestid, guestroom, gevent, gcost, sleepVal;
struct thread_data *guest_data;

guest_data = (struct thread_data *) guestData;

/*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for room to be available\n", guestid);
sem_wait(&roomSem); // guest wants a room; check to see if one is available

/*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for check-in\n", guestid);
sem_wait(&check_in); // if there is a room available, guest approaches check_in clerk; making him busy
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d goes to the check-in reservationist\n", guestid);
globalVar0 = guestid;
sem_post(&s1);  // event ordering
sem_wait(&s2);  // event ordering
guestroom = guest_data->room;   // gets room value from struct
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d receives Room %d and completes check-in\n", guestid, guestroom);

sem_post(&check_in); // event ordering. Check-In now available

gevent = getRandomLessThan(4);  // activity connected to 0, 1, 2, 3
guest_data[guestid].event = gevent; // assign to Guest's struct

switch(gevent)
{
    case(0): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Pool\n", guestid);
            pool++;

    case(1): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Resturant\n", guestid);
            resturant++;

    case(2): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Fitness Center\n", guestid);
            fitness_center++;

    case(3): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Business Center\n", guestid);
            business_center++;
}
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: %d\n", guestid, gevent);

sleepVal = getRandomLessThan(3) + 1;
printf("Guest %d sleeps for %d seconds\n", guestid, sleepVal);
sleep(sleepVal); // 0-2 + 1 = 1-3

/*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for check-out\n", guestid);
sem_wait(&check_out); // guest waits for check-out desk to be available
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room %d\n", guestid, guestroom);
globalVar1 = guestid;
globalVar2 = guestroom;
sem_post(&s3); // event ordering

sem_wait(&s4); // event ordering
gcost = guest_data[guestid].cost;
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d receives the total balance of $%d\n", guestid, gcost);
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d makes a payment\n", guestid);
sem_post(&s5); // event ordering

total_guests++;

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int getRandomLessThan(int x)
{
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand() % x;
printf("Random number: %d\n", r);

return r;
}

int GetOpenRoom()
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) // rooms.size and rooms.length throw errors
{
    if (rooms[i] = 1) // room available
    {
        rooms[i] = 0; // set to unavailable
        return i;
    }
}
}

void *CheckIn(void *guestData)
{
int i, guestid, guestroom;

for(i=0; i<NUM_GUESTS; i++)
{
    sem_wait(&s1); // event ordering

    guestid = globalVar0; // get the global variable set to the guestID
    /*output*/ printf("The check-in reservationist greets Guest %d\n", guestid);

    sem_wait(&roomSem); // use a room
    guestroom = GetOpenRoom(); // method returns index of open room
    thread_data_array[guestid].room = guestroom; // assign room to guest

    /*output*/ printf("Assign room %d to Guest %d\n", guestroom, guestid);

    sem_post(&s2); // event ordering
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *CheckOut(void *guestData)
{
int i, guestid, guestroom, gcost;

for(i=0; i<NUM_GUESTS; i++)
{
    sem_wait(&s3); // event ordering

    guestid = globalVar1;
    //guestroom = globalVar2;
    guestroom = thread_data_array[guestid].room;

    /*output*/ printf("The check-out reservationist greets Guest %d and receives the key from room %d\n", guestid, guestroom);
    rooms[guestroom] = 1; // room now available, set back to 1
    sem_post(&roomSem); // release a room

    /*output*/ printf("Calculate the balance for Guest %d\n", guestid);
    gcost = getRandomLessThan(300);     // 0 < cost < 300
    thread_data_array[guestid].cost = gcost;

    sem_post(&s4); // event ordering
    sem_wait(&s5); // event ordering
    /*output*/ printf("Receive $%d from Guest %d and complete the check-out\n", gcost, guestid);
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int rc;
int guest;
//struct thread_data *guest_data; //delete?

sem_init(&roomSem, 1, 5); //not 0 means shared between multiple processes, 5 is initial value
sem_init(&check_in, 1, 1);
sem_init(&check_out, 1, 1);
sem_init(&s1, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s2, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s3, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s4, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s5, 1, 0);

//rooms[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};

pthread_create(&desk[0], NULL, CheckIn, NULL);  // Check In runs on it's own now
pthread_create(&desk[1], NULL, CheckOut, NULL); // Check Out runs on it's own now

for(guest = 0; guest < NUM_GUESTS; guest++)
{
    thread_data_array[guest].guest_id = guest; // guest ID for each guest thread
    /*Output*/printf("Main(): Creating Thread: %d\n", guest);
    rc = pthread_create(&guests[guest], NULL, Guest, (void *)&thread_data_array[guest]); //Guest method, &thread_data_array[guest] argument
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create(Guest) is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

pthread_join(desk[0], NULL);
pthread_join(desk[1], NULL);
for(guest = 0; guest < NUM_GUESTS; guest++)
{
    pthread_join(guests[guest], NULL); // waits for each guest to complete and cleans memory space
}

printf("\t\tNumber of Customers\n");
printf("Total Guests:\t\t%d\n", total_guests);
printf("Pool:\t\t\t%d\n", pool);
printf("Resturant:\t\t%d\n", resturant);
printf("Fitness Center:\t\t%d\n", fitness_center);
printf("Business Center:\t%d\n", business_center);

sem_close(&roomSem);
sem_close(&check_in);
sem_close(&check_out);
sem_close(&s1);
sem_close(&s2);
sem_close(&s3);
sem_close(&s4);
sem_close(&s5);

}
```

Comment: It looks wrong for both `Guest` and `CheckIn` to call `sem_wait(&roomSem)`. Your best course of action is to use a debugger and/or add more debug statements to trace exactly what each thread is doing and what the values of the various semaphores and other variables are.

Comment: @kaylum ah sem_wait(&roomSem) is not supposed to be called in Guest. thanks for that!  and the only problem I have with adding debugging related statements is that an entire first iteration completes. Meaning I know where it hangs, I just don't know why.

Comment: The debugging statement aren't aiming just to tell you *where* it hangs. It can help you work out *why*. By printing out significant variables to check whether they are the values you expect. That's the whole point of debugging - to examine the state of your program to discover any unexpected state or execution paths.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: the function: `srand()`  should only be called once (1) in the whole program, not every time a random number is needed.  By calling it multiple times, the random sequence is restarted over and over.  Suggest placing the call to `srand()` near the beginning of the `main()` function.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   Amongst other things, the parameters to main() are not being used,  Suggest using the `int main( void )` function signature.  Overall, the posted code causes the compiler to output ~12 messages, All those message need to be fixed.

Comment: when coding use meaningful variable names.   Variable names should indicate usage or content (or better, both).   For instance s1...sx are meaningless.  Suggest names that show what the semaphore is used for.

Comment: If I understand the problem set correctly, then I suggest the program start a thread for each new guest and treat everything else as resources.  Then each resource handling function can have a unique mutex (although I think the pool should be able to handle multiple guests.)  Suggest thinking of the problem in terms of resources and data.  The 'guest' and associated data.  Each activity as a limited resource.   Then the 'guest' can also be in several different states, like: checking-in, checking-out, etc